# flex box button element not getting 50% of width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid red;
}

div button{
  flex:0 0 1;
  border:1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <button>Button one</button>
   <button>Button two</button>
</div>
```

Comment: why the question getting down vote? what is the issue?

Comment: `div button{
  width:49.5%;
  border:1px solid gray;
}`
Is that ok?

Comment: I am using a inbuild component. it has scenario like what is posted. but not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid red;
}

div button{
  flex: 1;
  border:1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <button>Button one</button>
   <button>Button two</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a typo "dispaly:flex;". :) 
Second, just put `flex-grow: 1;` on the buttons. 
Example code:

```
div{
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid red;
}

div button{
  flex-grow: 1;
  border:1px solid gray;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope. If the button text in one button is larger then the button will be larger than 50%. `flex-basis: 50%` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Should be this.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div button {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <button>Button one</button>
   <button>Button two</button>
</div>
```